# Deeplinking not working on Samsung Internet default browser

Tags: java, android, samsung, samsung-browser, samsung-internet

When the Samsung internet browser feature "Open links in other apps" is disabled then the browser does not return the correct deep link URL it should return links.xxxx.com which contains a success code instead it returns xxxx.com just with no success code. when "Open links in other apps" is turned on then it returns the correct URL.

**Note: It does work as expected in Google Chrome.**

Comment: What is your question? There is no requirement for a browser, email client, or anything else to support deeplinks at all, let alone by default.

Comment: is there any way to enable this option programtically ?

Comment: I would be rather stunned if Samsung had some sort of API to allow arbitrary third-party apps to enable deeplinks. Even if they do, that API would be unique to their app and would not impact Firefox, Outlook, or other apps that do not support deeplinks at all (or not by default).

Comment: Then what is the concept of deeplink if browser does not allow it?

Comment: There's an Api which give us URL, we open that url in default browser then user perform some authentication there and when the authentication is successful or unsuccessful a deep link is fired and it redirect back to our app where we recieve deeplink with code 200 in case of success or 400 in case of failure. So it is working fine in chrome but in samsung internet browser it does not return the correct deeplink instead it does navigate us back to our app but with wrong link which does not contain any status code. If we open that feature from settings of browser than it works correctly.

Comment: "Then what is the concept of deeplink if browser does not allow it?" -- different browsers and other clients will do different things. As you note, Chrome supports deeplinks by default. You will need some other mechanism for your authentication flow that will work in cases where the deeplink does not launch the app.